# Unknown binaryTarget debian-openssl-3.0.x and no custom binaries were provided error Command failed with exit code 1

Tags: openssl, prisma

Is there any way I can solve this problem? I recently updated to Ubuntu 22.04
Getting the problem while using Prisma.I can't run my project. I have use "@prisma/client": "2.20.1"

Error: Unknown binaryTarget debian-openssl-3.0.x and no custom binaries were provided
error Command failed with exit code 1.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to upgrade your prisma version to atleast `3.13.0`. Prisma has added support for OpenSSL 3.0 from version `3.13.0`, Ubuntu 22.04 is using OpenSSL 3.0 by default which is causing this issue for you.

Related GitHub Issue: [Support OpenSSL 3.0](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/11356)

Comment: Thank you so much. Saved me a few hours of debugging!

Comment: This sucks for those who cannot upgrade

Answer (score 11):

Run the following commands in project

```
npm install prisma --save-dev

npm install @prisma/client@dev prisma@dev
```

Comment: Thank you!  This worked for me and I am appreciative.  As an answer however, it does leave a bit to be desired.  If you have the time, would you consider adding some explanation as far as what we are doing with these commands and why they solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to install the correct version of Prisma on your machine as mentioned in the post above.

If you still have this problem, you probably need to check your **Node.js** version, You may get this error if you are using a version below 18.

Run this command in terminal `node -v`.

The great way to manage your node versions especially if you working on different projects is by using NVM - Node Version Manager.
So you can install Node 14, 16, 18 and ext...
And switch between versions depending on the project.
https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used serverless to deploy and this is how I got it resolved

1. I followed this Prisma tutorial [HERE](https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-client/deployment/serverless/deploy-to-aws-lambda#deployment-with-serverless-webpack)
2. I added block of code below to my webpack.config.js file

```
plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: './node_modules/.prisma/client/schema.prisma', to: './build/src' }, // you may need to change `to` here.
        { from: './node_modules/.prisma/client/libquery_engine-rhel-openssl-3.0.x.so.node', to: './build/src' }, // you may need to change `to` here.
      ],
    }),
```

Note `'./build/src'` yours could be different. Ensure it is same as your server file entry point file location.

Answer (score 0):

```
generator client {
  provider      = "prisma-client-js"
  binaryTargets = ["native", "debian-openssl-1.1.x", "debian-openssl-3.0.x"]
}
```

Adding those to schema.prisma works for me